# ksh :To store the output of a awk command in an array

Tags: ksh

I've the following `awk` command:

```
awk -F ' ' '{ print $NF }' log filename
```

And it gives the output as below:

```
06:00:00
parameters:
SDS
(2)
no
no
no
no

doc=4000000000).


information:
0
5898
5898
06:06:25
```

The problem is I need to save this in an array.
For example when I print or echo `$array[0]`

I should get `06:00:00`

and similarly

```
$array[1] = parameters:
.
.
.
$array[n] = 06:06:25
```

My end goal is to print them using a print statement i.e

```
printf("start time: %d  and end time: %d", array[0], array[n]")
```

Output

```
start time:06:00:00 and end time:06:06:25
```

Comment: `awk` has arrays, why do you need to use ksh arrays?

Comment: The printf statement as given will print 'start time: 6  and end time: 6', as the %d forces a conversion to integer.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
array=( $(awk -F ' ' '{ print $NF }' log filename) )
```

---

Given @Stephane's comment, another approach:

```
array=()
awk -F ' ' '{ print $NF }' log filename | while IFS= read -r line; do
    array+=( "$line" )
done
echo ${#array[@]}
echo ${array[1]}
echo ${array[17]}
```

```
17
06:00:00
06:06:25
```

works on my ksh "93u+"

Comment: That skips the empty lines and you'd have issues if the output contains tab or wildcard characters.

Comment: You'd also have issues using bash, pdksh, or some other shells which put variables defined/modified on the RHS of a pipe operator into a subshell, as `array` would be empty after the loop.

Comment: True, but fortunately the tag is ksh.

Comment: Many Linux systems and some other systems use pdksh as their "ksh".  I'd put the awk command in the background as a ksh coprocess and then have `read` use the `-p` argument to read from that coprocess, personally.  That works with both.

Comment: @glennjackman: I had tried the first approch earlier I was kicked saying this error.

`ksh: 0403-057 Syntax error: `(' is not expected.`

By tring your second approach I was getting the same error.

`ksh: 0403-057 Syntax error: `(' is not expected.`

Comment: @glennjackman : By the way m using **ksh88**

Comment: does ksh88 have arrays?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need the value of the last field of the first and last record.

This is best done in `awk` itself:

```
nawk 'NR == 1 {start=$NF}
    {last=$NF}
    END { 
         printf("start time: %s  and end time: %s", start, last)
    }' log filename
start time: 06:00:00  and end time: 06:06:25
```

Use an array indexed by `NR` (record number/line number) in `awk` if you want to access the fields at random:

```
nawk '{
    last[NR]=$(NF)
} END {
    print last[1],last[NR-1]
}' log
06:00:00 5898
```

Comment: @HenkLangevelt:What if I wanted get other values such as 0 and 5898 (last but one value) because if i want to make this one generic and change only the varibles to print differnt variable as per req.